# How to create WiFi Hotspot when connected to a wireless network with 2 network adapters in Windows 8.1?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I have 2 wireless network adapters - internal and external, so I want to create hotspot on second one while using 1st one for wireless connection.
Apart from Connectify software.

Comment: This requires third-party software to do this.

Comment: It's fine, but which one?

Comment: you have to bridge the 2 connections. Go to Network and Sharing Center>Advanced Adapter Settings (or something like that), there you will see both wifi adapters. select both of them and right click one and click `Bridge`. it should create another icon with the bridge name. Try this first.

Comment: @xR34P3Rx it took a while. next step?

Comment: go into the new bridge interface that was created, and see what options you have, i havent done this with 2 wifi cards but one wifi and one ethernet. I figured it would be similar.

Comment: I'm sure there is no such option for hotspot in windows.

Comment: And why the hell is my Question is downvoted I can't understand.

Comment: well this is why we are trying this arent we? you are getting downvoted because you didnt show any personal effort to figure out this issue on your own. this site is used as a last resort after everything YOU have attempted by yourself.

Comment: @xR34P3Rx I'm pretty sure this does require some effort otherwise it would have been solved by now!

Comment: No no no. What i mean is that the way your question is worded makes it look like you did "idk how to do this, I'm going to go to a forum and ask someone to hold my hand without going to Google first". This is what your question shows. Effort on your behalf. If you look at other questions with up votes they will include what the OP has tried, done, his/her setup, etc... You didn't show any of that.

Comment: Now I'm still willing to help, but you must learn to not be dependent on others as an IT. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Figured it out using CMD and providing a small tut so that others can benefit:-
1.To create a virtual WLAN network (HotSpot) enter in Elevated CMD: 
`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=yourhotspotname key=YourPassword`
2. Then start the HotSpot by giving the following command: `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`
3. Go to Adapter settings>choose wifi(external/internal which is connected to Internet)>properties>sharing>tick on allow other network and select newly created virtual adapter(with asterisk sign).
4. Hotspot is now online, to stop it enter in CMD: `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork`
5. Turning the computer off or rebooting also turns the HotSpot off. However, the HotSpot still exists (it "survives" the reboot); from now on you only need to turn it on when needed with the 
`netsh wlan start hostednetwork` command.