# How does one automate the setting up of a Windows 10 Wireless Hotspot using PowerShell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, netsh

Context: Windows 10, Powershell

It was suggested back in [2012](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2012/04/replace-netsh-with-windows-powershell-basic-network-cmdlets/) and again in [2016](http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2016/02/basic-networking-powershell-cmdlets-cheatsheet-to-replace-netsh-ipconfig-nslookup-and-more/) that one could use PowerShell instead of NETSH for network configuration.

My current regime each morning is to turn on a laptop computer, log in to a Windows 10 user account, connect to a telco via the USB wireless on WiFi-2, then share that connection to the rest of the network by turning on a Mobile Hotspot from the Settings panel. Finally, I make sure that Internet Sharing is still on in WiFi-2 and that it's going to the interface that was created by turning on Mobile Hotspot.

How do I automate the networking side of that? A [posting](https://superuser.com/questions/859738/how-to-create-wifi-hotspot-when-connected-to-a-wireless-network-with-2-network-a) on superuser describes the NETSH way. What's the PowerShell way?

Comment: Aside from using PS to call `netsh.exe`, which of course works, or using PS to P/Invoke the native APIs (which probably works but ew, white that in C# not a PS script) I don't think there is one. The relevant feature of netsh, "hostednetwork", is not present in Powershell.